# Can't connect to mysql using sqlalchemy. Library not loaded error

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to run a simple test code to connect ti a mysql db using sql alchemy.
The code is as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import (create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData)
import settings
import sys
try:
    db = create_engine('mysql://daniel:dani@localhost/test')
    db.connect()
except:
    print('opps ', sys.exc_info()[1])
```

I get the following error:

```
dlopen(//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: //anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
[Finished in 1.4s]
```

But running on terminal:

```
locate libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

I get:

```
/Applications/Dtella.app/Contents/Frameworks/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/Users/dpereira14/anaconda/envs/dato-env/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/Users/dpereira14/anaconda/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/Users/dpereira14/anaconda/pkgs/openssl-1.0.1k-1/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/anaconda/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/anaconda/pkgs/openssl-1.0.2g-0/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1j/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

I have no clue how to fix this error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also had some problems with SQLAlchemy with mysql, i changed localhost in the create_engine to 127.0.0.1:port, and also had to use pymysql. Ended up working with this:

`engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:port/db')`

pymysql is installed via pip.

Answer (score 0):

You are using python , so you have add mysqldb with mysql. Try the below code.

```
try:
    db = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://daniel:dani@localhost/test')
    db.connect()
except:
    print('opps ', sys.exc_info()[1])
```